# Spring Boot connect to Atlas MongoDB issue

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect my Atlas MongoDB instance from Spring Boot using the following properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://<usr>:<pass>@<my-cluster-prefix>.gkyoqkx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spring.data.mongodb.database=my-db
```

The connection string I've got from the Atlas "Connect"->"Connect your application" so should be valid.
But when I start my app I see the following exception:

```
2022-08-22 17:13:42.836  INFO 52641 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ac-opxd8w6-shard-00-02.gkyoqkx.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:684) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:555) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:381) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:329) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:101) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:45) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:182) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 34.95.185.60 found
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1506) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:552) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

which is looking strange since by default it shouldn't be using SSL to connect (afaik).
I also whitelisted all IPs by adding `0.0.0.0/0` to the Network Access in Atlas.

And btw, when I am trying to connect from my Mac with `mongosh` and the same connection URI it works perfectly.

Any piece of advice is appreciated.

Atlas MongoDB version: 5.0.10,
Mongo driver version: 4.6.1

Comment: are you trying to connect with ip? There seems to be SSL certificate and that is probably generated for domain name instead of ip. You should either change that url to point to dns or import that certificate to your keystore and trust it.

Comment: that URL points to DNS name, not IP

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here, I fixed it upgrading Java version from 11 to 17, you shoud try it as an alternative solution.
This is a known bug in mongodb-driver-sync with JKD 13.0.2, solved in Java versions >= 13.0.5.
[check official mongo forum discussion here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/sslhandshakeexception-should-not-be-presented-in-certificate-request/12493/3)

The question is: to upgrade Java is not a solution if the issue is according to the connection driver. I'll come here again if I find something new.

Comment: you should try add "-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2" to build params, it fixed the problem here with Java 11.

Comment: seems to not working with Java 8

Comment: do you believe upgrading Java would be the only option?

Comment: with java 8 you should try add "-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1" to build params. You must check the mongo driver version too, if it is compatible 
`<groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId> <version>4.2</version>` Try different versions.